# javascript - Age calculation

Tags: javascript

Having 2 javascript Dates,

first is birthdate
and second is a date to calculate age from that date.

What should be the best way to do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
function getAge(d1, d2){
    d2 = d2 || new Date();
    var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    return Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
}
console.log( getAge(new Date(1978, 10, 3)) );
```

Be careful with the month. Javascript counts them from 0.
 `1978, 10, 3` means the November 3th, 1978

Comment: This doesn't properly handle leap years.

Comment: @jaaksarv Do you have an example? I assumed the `floor` would shave the differences for most cases.

Comment: console.log( getAge(new Date(2001, 1, 28), new Date(2004, 1, 28)) );
This returns 2, but should return 3.

There are tons of examples that do not work. Leap year logic is much more complicated and can't be solved with Floor or other rounding. 

Much more complicated results are around years 1900 and 2100 that are NOT leap years so there are 7 years with 365 days in a row.

Answer (score 49):

```
function calculateAge (birthDate, otherDate) {
    birthDate = new Date(birthDate);
    otherDate = new Date(otherDate);

    var years = (otherDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear());

    if (otherDate.getMonth() < birthDate.getMonth() || 
        otherDate.getMonth() == birthDate.getMonth() && otherDate.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
        years--;
    }

    return years;
}
```

Example:

```
var age = calculateAge("02/24/1991", "02/24/2010"); // Format: MM/DD/YYYY
```

Comment: To me, this is the most elegant solution. I've always seen programmers stumble over this and resorting to a lot of calculations ... until they realize how people determine how old someone is :)

Comment: This is definitely the better answer. Any calculation that does math around year-seconds fails to account for the arbitrary nature of dates: laws changing daylight savings, leap years, etc. Let the native Date library deal with that; you really do not want to. Otherwise, be prepared to be wrong by a day or so around their birthday.

Comment: That's the most complete answer. It even handles better leap years.

Comment: Yes when considering age calculation we need to work with years and days and not with ceil and floor values which will incorrectly pushed to wrong values

Answer (score 6):

```
function getAge(dateString) {
  var now = new Date();
  var today = new Date(now.getYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate());

  var yearNow = now.getYear();
  var monthNow = now.getMonth();
  var dateNow = now.getDate();

  var dob = new Date(dateString.substring(6,10),
                     dateString.substring(0,2)-1,                   
                     dateString.substring(3,5)                  
                     );

  var yearDob = dob.getYear();
  var monthDob = dob.getMonth();
  var dateDob = dob.getDate();
  var age = {};
  var ageString = "";
  var yearString = "";
  var monthString = "";
  var dayString = "";


  yearAge = yearNow - yearDob;

  if (monthNow >= monthDob)
    var monthAge = monthNow - monthDob;
  else {
    yearAge--;
    var monthAge = 12 + monthNow -monthDob;
  }

  if (dateNow >= dateDob)
    var dateAge = dateNow - dateDob;
  else {
    monthAge--;
    var dateAge = 31 + dateNow - dateDob;

    if (monthAge < 0) {
      monthAge = 11;
      yearAge--;
    }
  }

  age = {
      years: yearAge,
      months: monthAge,
      days: dateAge
      };

  if ( age.years > 1 ) yearString = " years";
  else yearString = " year";
  if ( age.months> 1 ) monthString = " months";
  else monthString = " month";
  if ( age.days > 1 ) dayString = " days";
  else dayString = " day";


  if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + ", " + age.months + monthString + ", and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = "Only " + age.days + dayString + " old!";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " old. Happy Birthday!!";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " and " + age.months + monthString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.months + monthString + " and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years > 0) && (age.months == 0) && (age.days > 0) )
    ageString = age.years + yearString + " and " + age.days + dayString + " old.";
  else if ( (age.years == 0) && (age.months > 0) && (age.days == 0) )
    ageString = age.months + monthString + " old.";
  else ageString = "Oops! Could not calculate age!";

  return ageString;
}

// A bit of jQuery to call the getAge() function and update the page...
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#submitDate").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#age").html(getAge($("input#date").val()));

  });
});

and HTML IS
```

**Date (MM/DD/YYYY):**  Calculate Age

Age: 7 years, 1 month, and 15 days old.

Comment: your code is working but i wonder why. the problem im facing is your constant `31`. a month can contain 28-31 days. but still your code is working. how come ?

Answer (score 2):

Convert the date to milliseconds since the epoch using [getTime()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp), then subtract the values and convert the result back to years:

```
const MS_PER_YEAR = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.2425;
var years = Math.floor((dateNow.getTime() - dateThen.getTime()) / MS_PER_YEARS);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one example using **moment.js** library which is very common now days. Just adding this answer in many of other answers.

```js
var banner = $("#banner-message")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  var inputValue = $("#txtInput").val();
  var age = parseInt(moment().diff(inputValue,'years',true));
  
$("#spantext").html(age + ' years.');
  
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#banner-message {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 300px;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

#banner-message.alt {
  background: #0084ff;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 40px;
  width: 200px;
}

#banner-message.alt button {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="banner-message">
  <p>Enter Date: <input type='text' id='txtInput' value='1981-12-25' /></p>
  <label>Age is : </label><span id='spantext'></span> <br/>
  <p><button>Calculate Age</button></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Now days I would use `dayjs` as it is smaller and dependency free. API and syntax are mostly the same.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to do this is using [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).

We have two dates, the birth date (birthDate) and the other date used to calculate age from (specificDate). You can avoid this parameter and get the current age.

```
moment(specificDate).diff(moment(birthDate), 'years');
```

Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

The best way would probably be to convert the date into a timestamp, probably using `parse()` if the date is a string. Then simply subtracting the numbers and converting the new number back to a date using `new Date(milliseconds)`

This might not be too accurate for dates before the 1/1/1970 though, so the alternative method of subtracting days, months, etc... separately would be more suitable.

Comment: Depending on the accuracy required, this may well be not what is wanted. If it is completed years only (for age) then this is perfectly good. Subtracting dates to get a period is complex - what constitutes a month or a week is very much dependant on the implementation of the conversion back to a date - which will have made its own assumptions as to what constitutes eg a month (30 days; 29 days; 31 days?)  As you say dates before 1/1/1970 will be a problem and when calculating ages from birthdates is likely to be a substantial problem (there are more than a few people who are older than 41).

Comment: Converting the dates into milliseconds since the epoch and subtracting them is the most straightforward and I thought most accurate way to work out differences between dates, but it does have this pre-1970 issue. The browser should automatically take into account days of the month, leap years, etc....

One solution might be to modify the pre 1970 dates with an offset to 1970 before calculating the difference then re-add the offset afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

```
var birth = new Date('07/11/2003');
var check = new Date();

var milliDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // a day in milliseconds;


var ageInDays = (check - birth) / milliDay;

var ageInYears =  Math.floor(ageInDays / 365 );
```

example http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/XDKa3/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you are in an huge Javascript project, you maybe [use|need to use] a framework...

With [Mootools More](http://mootools.net/more/), you have a [Date Type](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Date) with a  [diff method](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Date#Date%3adiff) and a [timeDiff method](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Types/Date.Extras#Date%3atimeDiff) that can fit to your needs.

It even [provide localisation](http://mootools.net/docs/more/Locale/Date) !

Answer (score 1):

I've modified Mic's response to allow for today being the user's birthday. The difference is the date you're checking the age of should be set to midnight of that day and/or the current date should be set to 23:59:59. An example would be to see if the user is 18 today, this will return 18.

```
function getAge(d1){
    var now = new Date();
    var d2 = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate(), 23, 59, 59);
    var diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();
    return Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25));
}
console.log(getAge(new Date(1992, 10, 17, 0, 0, 0)));
```

Answer (score 1):

**This handle leap year use case also:**

```js
const getAgeFromBirthDate = (year, month, day) => {
   const date = new Date();
   date.setFullYear(date.getFullYear() - year);
   date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - month);
   //date.setDate(date.getDate() - day);
   return date;
};

console.log( getAgeFromBirthDate(1994, 07, 19).getFullYear() );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAge(dateOfBirth, tillDate) {
    var dob = new Date(dateOfBirth);
    var endDt = new Date(tillDate) || new Date();
    return new Date(endDt.getTime() - dob.getTime()).getUTCFullYear() - 1970;
}
```

**Example:** `console.log(getAge('1/1/2000', '1/1/2016')); // Format: MM/DD/YYYY`

Comment: I think your simplified solution fails for console.log(getAge('1/2/2000', '1/1/2016'));

Comment: console.log(getAge('1/2/2000', '1/1/2016')); returns "15" is correct answer. Could you please try some other dates and validate

Comment: I'm still getting "16" as the output. https://gist.github.com/WallaceKelly/a6a43e779feef431c828304e71633858

Answer (score 0):

Get age calculating by current year

```
calculateExp(birthDate) {
    birthDate = new Date(birthDate);
    var now = new Date();
    otherDate = new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate());
    var years = (otherDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear() );


    if (otherDate.getMonth() < birthDate.getMonth() || otherDate.getMonth() == birthDate.getMonth() && otherDate.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
        years--;
    }

    return years;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This script helps you do the following;

- Calculate age using start date and end date
- Determine if year is leap year or not
- Calculate the number of days in a month
- Determine if it is an end month
- Calculate the number of weekends between two dates
- Determine the next day from a given date

Here is the script; https://github.com/amoschihi/age-calculator

```
determineAge('2001-01-24','2022-04-03');
  // output: 21 Years, 2 Months and 9 Days
```