# Calculate age from "Date" HTML element

Tags: javascript

I have an HTML form with "Date" element and a submit button. There are 2 functions. One is for calculating age from given birth date in the "date" HTML element. The other function is for comparing the age with minimal allowed age. I need help to complete it. See my questions in remarks in code. Yes, I have seen other similar questions. I would like to learn and not just copy/paste. If I understand what is wrong with my code / syntax, then I will learn better. Thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    var minAge = 18;

    var curDate = new Date();

    var curr_year = curDate.getFullYear();
    var curr_month = curDate.getMonth();


    //Calculates age from given Birth Date in the form//
    function _calcAge() {

        var dt1 = document.getElementById('date').value;
        var birth_date = new Date(dt1);

        var birth_year = birth_date.getFullYear();
        var birth_month = birth_date.getMonth();
        var calc_year = curr_year - birth_year;
        var calc_month = curr_month - birth_month;

        //The following below is what I am not sure about. 
        //I need to combine years and months and
        //convert them into a string??? Is this syntax dead wrong?

    var final_result = (calc_year && "." && calc_month).toString();

        // final result should be a number with a decimal point, example: 35.5
        final_result = parseFloat;

        return (final_result);
        alert(final_result);
    }

    //Compares calculated age with minimum age and acts according to rules//
    function _setAge() {

        var age = _calcAge();
        //alert("my age is " + age);
        if (age < minAge) {
            alert("You are not allowed into the site. The minimum age is 18!");
        } else

            alert("Welcome to my Site");
            window.open(main.htm, _self);

    }


    </script>

     <form>
      Date Of Birth: <input type="date" name="date of birth" id="date" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="_setAge();" />

     </form>

    </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get it to work. Credit also goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/444991/matt for the part I borrowed from him here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4076440/3189118

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
     <title></title>
   </head>
     <body>
      <script type="text/javascript">

      var minAge = 18;
      var today = new Date()
      //Calculates age from given Birth Date in the form//
       function _calcAge(birthDate, givenDate) {
        givenDate = new Date(today);
        var dt1 = document.getElementById('date').value;
        var birthDate = new Date(dt1);
        var years = (givenDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear());

        if (givenDate.getMonth() < birthDate.getMonth() ||
     givenDate.getMonth() == birthDate.getMonth() && givenDate.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
            years--;
        }

        return years;
    }

    //Compares calculated age with minimum age and acts according to rules//
    function _setAge() {

        var age = _calcAge();
        if (age < minAge) {
            alert("You are not allowed into the site. The minimum age is 18!");
        } else

            alert("Welcome to my Site");


    }


</script>

<form>
    Date Of Birth: <input type="date" name="date of birth" id="date" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onClick="_setAge();" />

</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can add or subtract javascript dates by basic mathematical functions.

Just make a new Date for today `var Today = new Date()` and then substract the date from the form. You get the difference in milliseconds.

Now you just need to convert them to years/months by dividing them by `(1000*60*60*24*365)`

So just do:

```
var difference = (curDate - birth_date)/((1000*60*60*24*365);
var differenceString = "The difference is: " + difference.toFixed(1) + " years.";
```

The `toFixed(1);` returns your number with 1 decimal point.

And always remember JavaScripts Dates Months are zero-based.

Your second function should work then too.

[Here is a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gCYA2/1/)

Comment: Thanks, but... If we do this your way (and it looks good), how do we account for years that have 366 days? Can't I somehow use the build in functionality of the "date" element to account for all of that?

Comment: The subtraction automatically subtracts 366 days if there are any years with 366. With rounding to 1 decimal point you cover up 0.1*365 so 36.5 days of tolerance so like +/- 18 days...the possibility that there is not there until you have an age higher than 4*18 days until the one decimal might be wrong by 1 I guess. Might not cover really every case but precise enough i think. If the result is right or wrong depends on how you define a year. If the year you are calculating with is defined with 365 days its fine like this.

Answer (score 2):

This will work you can simply replace code with this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var minAge = 18;
        function _calcAge() {
            var date = new Date(document.getElementById("date").value);
            var today = new Date();

            var timeDiff = Math.abs(today.getTime() - date.getTime());
            var age1 = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)) / 365;
            return age1;
        }
        //Compares calculated age with minimum age and acts according to rules//
        function _setAge() {

            var age = _calcAge();
            //alert("my age is " + age);
            if (age < minAge) {
                alert("You are not allowed into the site. The minimum age is 18!");
            } else

                alert("Welcome to my Site");
            window.open(main.htm, _self);

        }


    </script>
    <form>
    Date Of Birth:
    <input type="date" name="date of birth" id="date" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" onclick="_setAge();" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try This..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Person Details</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        Birthday: <input type="date" name="bday" id="birth_date">
        <br><br>
    </form>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">view</button><br>

    <p id="age"></p>
    <script>
        function myFunction() {


            var dobString = document.getElementById("birth_date").value;
            var calculatedValue = calculate_age(dobString);

        }

        function calculate_age(dobString) {
            var diff_ms = Date.now() - Date.parse(dobString);

            var yearString = "";
            var monthString = "";
            var dayString = "";

            var yearValue = Math.floor(diff_ms / 31536000000);
            console.log("Years ", yearValue);
            var monthValue = Math.floor((diff_ms % 31536000000) / 2592000000);
            console.log("Months ", monthValue);
            var dayValue = Math.floor(((diff_ms % 31536000000) % 2592000000) / 86400000);
            console.log("Days ", dayValue);
            // var calculatedValue = yearValue + " years " + monthValue + " months " + dayValue + " days"; // calculate and execute age

            if (yearValue > 1) yearString = " years";
            else yearString = " year";
            if (monthValue > 1) monthString = " months";
            else monthString = " month";
            if (dayValue > 1) dayString = " days";
            else dayString = " day";

            if ((yearValue > 0) && (monthValue > 0) && (dayValue > 0))
                var calculatedValue = yearValue + yearString + " " + monthValue + monthString + " " + dayValue + dayString + " ";
            else if ((yearValue > 0) && (monthValue > 0) && (dayValue == 0))
                var calculatedValue = yearValue + yearString + " " + monthValue + monthString + " ";
            else if ((yearValue > 0) && (monthValue == 0) && (dayValue > 0))
                var calculatedValue = yearValue + yearString + " " + dayValue + dayString + " ";
            else if ((yearValue == 0) && (monthValue > 0) && (dayValue > 0))
                var calculatedValue = monthValue + monthString + " " + dayValue + dayString + " ";
            else if ((yearValue == 0) && (monthValue == 0) && (dayValue > 0))
                var calculatedValue = dayValue + dayString + " ";

            document.getElementById("age").innerHTML = "Age : " + calculatedValue;

        }`

    </script>`
</body>

</html>
```