# How to calculate age in years and months based on date of birth in Microsoft CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am aware this is done using a javascript library.  Currently, the only examples I've found for CRM 2011 involve calculating the age in years only using this code:

```
function CalcAge()
{
var now = new Date(); //Todays Date   
var birthday = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("birthdate").getValue(); //Get the Date of Birth value   
var diff = now.getMonth() - birthday.getMonth();  //Check to see if Birthday  has already passed

if (diff > -1) //If Birthday has already occurred   
{
    var bd1 = now.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear();

    //set the age attribute 
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("frc_age").setValue(bd1.toString());  
}
else //If Birthday has not already occurred  
{
    var bd2 = now.getFullYear() - birthday.getFullYear() - 1;
    Xrm.Page.getAttribute("frc_age").setValue(bd2.toString()); 
}
}
```

I need help implementing a similar function that also accounts for the months.

-Thank You

Comment: for month, you mean for example: "23 years and 7 months old"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try below code if DOB is in format "MM/dd/yyyy". You can also change it for other formats accordingly.

```
var now = new Date(); //Todays Date   
var birthday = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("birthdate").getValue();
birthday=birthday.split("/");   

var dobMonth= birthday[0]; 
var dobDay= birthday[1];
var dobYear= birthday[2];

var nowDay= now.getDate();
var nowMonth = now.getMonth() + 1;  //jan = 0 so month + 1
var nowYear= now.getFullYear();

var ageyear = nowYear - dobYear;
var agemonth = nowMonth - dobMonth;
var ageday = nowDay- dobDay;
if (agemonth <= 0) {
       ageyear--;
       agemonth = (12 + agemonth);
        }
if (nowDay < dobDay) {
      agemonth--;
      ageday = 30 + ageday;
      }
var val = ageyear + "-" + agemonth + "-" + ageday;
return val;
```

you can also use some of below:

[Simple age calculator in JavaScript](https://gist.github.com/iboB/1363623)

[Calculate age in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-in-javascript)

[javascript - Age calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076321/javascript-age-calculation)

[How can I calculate the number of years betwen two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-betwen-two-dates)

Comment: This gives incorrect results:

Example:
Currentdate : feb 02 2017
Birthdate :   feb 25 1994

Returns 
23 years 0 months 12 days.....

Should be
22 years 11 months 9 days