# meteorjs convert date of birth to age

Tags: meteor

How to convert date of birth to age.

Example input from user, "Tue Aug 16 2016 11:13:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)"

Based on the above, expected output is 6 days old.

Thanks

Comment: It is not related to Meteor. Are you getting this as a string or as a date object?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - Age calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076321/javascript-age-calculation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://momentjs.com/

> moment(yourDate).fromNow();

Answer (score 1):

The following should be an easy way to do it. You might want to add checking to ensure it's not a future date.

```
moment("Tue Aug 16 2016 11:13:59 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)").fromNow(true)
```

Check the charts from the [Moment.js docs for fromNow](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/) to see what it will return for different ranges. You can use fromNow source code as template for custom code in order to format with different set of ranges.

Add library to meteor as per [Moment.js docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/meteor/)

```
meteor add momentjs:moment
```