# Calculate Birthdate from given age using javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I calculate Birthdate from given age using javascript.

example:

I am entering my age as 23 years 1 month 26 days.

then I need to get birthdate as 1995-05-30.

how this can be done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript - Age calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076321/javascript-age-calculation)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate age given the birth date in the format YYYYMMDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4060004/calculate-age-given-the-birth-date-in-the-format-yyyymmdd)

Comment: You could try convert it to seconds, awell as the current date time, then substract and the creating a new date from it

Comment: This is not a duplicate of "age given birth date" @Durga since this question is the opposite: "birth date given age".

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question @JorgeFuentesGonzález either, since again that question is age from dates whereas this question is date from age.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with dates, I recommend using moment library:

https://momentjs.com/

Using moment you can easily subtract intervals from dates. For example:

`moment().subtract(10, 'days')`

In your case:

```
var bDay = moment().subtract(23, 'years');
bDay.subtract(1, 'months');
bDay.subtract(26, 'days');
```

Comment: Great solution.Next level.

Comment: You can do the same without moment and also 3 lines of code in vanilla JavaScript. Using a library for EVERYTHING in JavaScript is becoming a problem. Yet Another Framework Syndrome.