# converting long timestamp to extract year in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, timestamp

From my backend I get an object with date of birth that is a long value.For frontend I use angular 4 (typescript) I would like to extract year from that date of birth to be able to calculate age but I have no idea how to parse long to some kind of Date object in typescript. Could you give me a hint where to look for information?

Maybe something along lines of:

```
a: Number;
let a = new Date(762861060).getFullYear();
```

Thank you for help

Comment: Welcome to **Stack Overflow**, please try adding some code, then we can start trying to help **you**! :)

Comment: I edited my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not far off, if you don't need fractional years:

```
var birthDate = new Date(762861060);
var laterDate = new Date();  
var yearsBetween = laterDate.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try simple code like this:

```
var birthDate = new Date(762861060);
var todayDate = new Date();    
var milliDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24; // a day in milliseconds;

var ageInDays = (todayDate - birthDate) / milliDay;   
var ageInYears =  Math.floor(ageInDays / 365 );

console.log(ageInYears)
```

See more related answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-betwen-two-dates) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076321/javascript-age-calculation) questions...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Moment.js:

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

var diff = moment.duration((moment(762861060)).diff(moment()));
var age_in_days = diff.days();
var age_in_years = diff.years();
```

Comment: a minor correction var diff = moment.duration((moment()).diff(moment(762861060)));