# Age Calculate by years in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to develop a children magazine website and making a form for  children, in this form i am trying to take the input as (date) type and calculate the difference by years and return a message or alert if the age was 18=< age <= 6,  now I've tried many codes that I found in this site or other sites as :
1. [javascript - Age calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076321/javascript-age-calculation) 
( i tried : getTime() and other codes ) 
2. https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-date-exercise-18.php
and many had the same ideas, but all of them didn't work ..

here is the code :

```
</head>
<body>
    <input type="date" id="userage" name="userage" onchange=""/>
    <p id="k" ></p>
    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById('k').value ; 
        var b = Date.parse(a) ;
        var c = new Date(b);
        var d = c.getFullYear();

        function useragefun(birthday){ 
            var e = new Date(); 
            var f = e.getFullYear(); 

            var g = Math.floor(f - birthday);

            if (g >= 18 || g <= 6 ){

                document.getElementById('k').innerHTML = "You better sign in the adults form"; 


            }else "" ;





         }



    </script>
</body>
```

// it could be this or an alert ..

Comment: You're question isn't all that clear. what are you loading in var a? and why should Date parse it?

Comment: you don't even call `useragefun` at all in your code

Comment: your script reads and parses element with id `k` - which is a `p` ... and `p` do not have a `value`

Comment: because the getelementbyid().value will return a string . so i prased it to a date to get the year .

Comment: @JaromandaX sorry i forgot to add it in this code but i tried it before and it still didn't work .

Comment: you forgot to add what? the ability for a `p` element to have a `value` - don't bother, it can not have a value, it is not an input element

Comment: @JaromandaX i called useragefun  and changed <p> to <div> still didn't work .

Comment: @saronstar a `<div>` still doesn't have a `value` property.

Comment: <script>
            var a = document.getElementById('userage').nodeValue ; 
            var b = Date.parse(a) ;
            var c = new Date(b);
            var d = c.getFullYear();       // okay now ?

Comment: `document.getElementById('userage').nodeValue` why would you try to use `value` for an element that doesn't have one, but then when accessing an element that DOES have value, you try to use `nodeValue` instead ... it's like you're deliberately using the wrong properties - and furthermore, the input wont have a value on page load - which is when you're trying to get its value

Comment: and you STILL haven't shown how you intend on calling `useragefun`

Comment: @JaromandaX onchange="useragefun(c)" ,also both .value and .nodeValue return (NAN)

Comment: `useragefun(c)` - what is `c`?

Comment: 18<= age <= 6 is mathematically impossible. It is impossible for something to be greater than or equal to 18 and less than. or equal to 6 at the same time. It seems you meant 6<= age <= 18 instead

Comment: @jro OP's code logic suggests you need to *sign the adult form* if you are 18 or over, or 6 and under! so god knows what it really wants

Comment: @jaromanda-x Yep it's reflected in the question too.

Comment: The question asks for mathematically impossible, the code suggests a child under six is an adult :p - i.e. the CODE can be true, but the *text* asks for the impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what you wanted, but this seems to be it:

```js
        function useragefun(birthday){ 
               let birthDate = new Date(birthday),
         today = new Date(),
               years = (today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear());

    if (today.getMonth() < birthDate.getMonth() || 
        today.getMonth() == birthDate.getMonth() && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
        years--;
    }
    if (years >= 18 || years <= 6 ){
                document.getElementById('k').innerHTML = "You better sign in the adults form"; 

            } else "";
         }
```

```html
    <input type="date" id="userage" name="userage" onchange="useragefun(this.value)"/>
    <p id="k" ></p>
```

Comment: it works , thank you very much . it was a great help , but can you explain to me why did you used :  `if (today.getMonth() < birthDate.getMonth() || 
                today.getMonth() == birthDate.getMonth() && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate()) {
                     years--;
                }`

Comment: Because people are born on days other than today

Comment: i ment why `years--; ` :)

Comment: because people have a birthday this year but after today ... if you were born on the 1st april 2001 you're not 18 yet ... herpa derp ... simple maths