# Calculating age in Javascript using simple JS functions and methods

Tags: javascript, date

I am writing a program in **JS** to find age. The parameters to a function `calculateAge ()` are day, month, year (DOB of a person) and output should be the age of the person.
I tried the following code

```
  let calculateAge = function(day, month, year){
      var myBirthDate = new Date(calculateAge),
      myBirthYear = myBirthDate.getFullYear(),
      myBirthMonth = myBirthDate.getMonth(),
      myBirthDay = myBirthDate.getDay()
      let currentDate = new Date(),
      currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear(),
      currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth(),
      currentDay= currentDate.getDay()
      var age = currentYear - myBirthYear
      var ageMonth = currentMonth - myBirthMonth
      var ageDay = currentDay-myBirthDay
      if (ageMonth<0 || (ageMonth == 0 && ageDay<0)){
      age = parseInt(age)-1
      }
    
    }; alert (calculateAge(24,04,1993))
```

The output is undefined instead of *27*.
My understanding is, **JS** does not know if the input parameters are date values. So I would like to know if there's a way to tell **JS** that the parameters are actually the date values (day,month,year format).

Comment: Welcome to SO and hope you have a good learning curve. 
What do you think the code flow here is?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I calculate the number of years betwen two dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8152426/how-can-i-calculate-the-number-of-years-betwen-two-dates)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript - Age calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076321/javascript-age-calculation)

Comment: Well in my understanding the parameters are just numbers and I want JS to treat the parameters as date. Since the default date format is yyyy-mm-dd, JS is taking the function parameters just like some other numbers. Since, I want the user to give his DOB as dd,mm,yyyy the date format should be changed.

Comment: @Shreyas, I think in the new Date() I should pass the parameters i.e. day,month,year rather than the function itself. Is that right?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Let me check this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow!

You were close to calculating the age. You were not passing the function parameters into the `Date` constructor and some other minor issues such as trying to use `parseInt` on a value that is already an integer:

```js
let calculateAge = function(day, month, year) {
  var myBirthDate = new Date(year, month - 1, day),
    myBirthYear = myBirthDate.getFullYear(),
    myBirthMonth = myBirthDate.getMonth(),
    myBirthDay = myBirthDate.getDay();
  var currentDate = new Date(),
    currentYear = currentDate.getFullYear(),
    currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth(),
    currentDay = currentDate.getDay();
  var ageMonth = currentMonth - myBirthMonth;
  var ageDay = currentDay - myBirthDay;
  var age = currentYear - myBirthYear;
  if (ageMonth < 0 || (ageMonth == 0 && ageDay < 0)) {
    age = age - 1;
  }
  return age;
};
```

Comment: Hello Robert, Thank you for your answer and for correcting the code. One more question- is it necessary to have the date in yyyy-mm-dd format in Java Script? Coz here in India the convention is dd,mm,yyyy. So is there any way that I can change the format in Indian convention?

Comment: You need to pass in the arguments to the `Date` constructor as year, month, day (in that order). If you want to format the date, there are methods of doing that: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString

Comment: Since ECMAScript months are zero based, likely the OP needs `new Date(year, month - 1, day)`.

Comment: Adding to the same code, instead of passing the values in the function call, if I asked the user to give his/her birthdate and then passed the prompted value in the function call the output is NaN. Why the output is not a number? Since I asked the user to give his birthday, then he would anyway give the day, month and year.

Comment: @ShreeyogRajopadhye You need to make sure to call `calculateAge` with numbers and not strings. Make sure that when you receive values from the user, that you convert any strings to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Using the experimental [Temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) proposal:

```js
const calculateAge = (day, month, year) => {
  const birthday = Temporal.DateTime.from({ day, month, year });
  const today = Temporal.DateTime.from(Temporal.now.date());
  return today.difference(birthday, { largestUnit: 'years' }).years;
}

calculateAge(24, 4, 1993); // 27
```