# How to calculate age in YYYY years MM months DD days

Tags: javascript, date

I have been trying to make an age calculator which is a challenge from front end mentor. I have figured out the logic to finding the years and months using the Date() method in JavaScript. But my days age is not accurate, i cant seem to figure out the logic behind how I can show the number of days old someone is according to different months, as some months have 30 some 31 and February has 28.
here is my code below.

```
const days = document.getElementById("days"); // the day input box
const months = document.getElementById("months"); // the month input box
const years = document.getElementById("years"); // the year input box

function calculateYears() {
  var dayValue = document.getElementById("day").value; // day value
  var monthValue = document.getElementById("month").value; //month value
  var yearValue = document.getElementById("year").value; //year value

  var birthday = new Date(yearValue, monthValue - 1, dayValue); // birthday in milliseconds

  var today = Date.now(); // todays in milliseconds
  var diff = today - birthday; //age in milliseocnds

  var currentAgeYears = Math.floor(diff / 31556952000); // age in milliseconds/ by milliseconds in a year
  var ageMonths = Math.floor(diff / 2629746000); // age in milisecond / by milliseconds in a month
  var currentAgeMonths = ageMonths % 12; // remainder  total age in months / 12 to get age in current year's month
  var ageDays = diff / 86400000; // age in milisecond / by milliseconds in a day
  
  
  
  currentAgeDays = Math.floor(ageDays % 30); // this is where i need help what logic can i use for days 

  years.innerHTML = currentAgeYears + " "; 
  months.innerHTML = currentAgeMonths + " ";
  days.innerHTML = currentAgeDays + " ";
}
```

i need help in this line of code
`var ageDays = diff / 86400000; // age in milisecond / by milliseconds in a day

currentAgeDays = Math.floor(ageDays % 30); // this is where i need help what logic can i use for days`

i am going to attach a image of my output. as the day of testing this it is August 24 2023. the output should be 1 year 0 months and 0 days yet the days don't match.

Any help would be appreciated [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcosH.png)

Comment: you can see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076321/javascript-age-calculation

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAge(fromdate, todate) {
  if (todate) todate = new Date(todate);
  else todate = new Date();

  var age = [],
    fromdate = new Date(fromdate),
    y = [todate.getFullYear(), fromdate.getFullYear()],
    ydiff = y[0] - y[1],
    m = [todate.getMonth(), fromdate.getMonth()],
    mdiff = m[0] - m[1],
    d = [todate.getDate(), fromdate.getDate()],
    ddiff = d[0] - d[1];

  if (mdiff < 0 || (mdiff === 0 && ddiff < 0)) --ydiff;
  if (mdiff < 0) mdiff += 12;
  if (ddiff < 0) {
    fromdate.setMonth(m[1] + 1, 0);
    ddiff = fromdate.getDate() - d[1] + d[0];
    --mdiff;
  }
  if (ydiff > 0) age.push(ydiff + " year" + (ydiff > 1 ? "s " : " "));
  if (mdiff > 0) age.push(mdiff + " month" + (mdiff > 1 ? "s" : ""));
  if (ddiff > 0) age.push(ddiff + " day" + (ddiff > 1 ? "s" : ""));
  if (age.length > 1) age.splice(age.length - 1, 0, " and ");
  return age.join("");
}

getAge("1/25/1974");
```

---

output
37 years 8 months and 26 days

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following logic to calculate age:

```
function getAge (year, month, day) {
    const birth = new Date(year, month - 1, day)
    const now = new Date()
    const diff = new Date(now.valueOf() - birth.valueOf())
    return Math.abs(diff.getFullYear() - 1970)
}
```

Comment: but this will only output the age in years